Android, Kotlin, Timber: Timber перестает вести логи в корутинах
У меня во ViewModel такой код:
Timber.d("generatePDF body")

viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
   Timber.d("generatePDF body 2")
}

Первый лог -> "generatePDF body", показывается, второй лог - нет.
В Application.onCreate() у меня:
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
   Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}

Как подружить Timber с корутинами?
P.S. если нельзя, то что мне делать чтобы вывести логи в корутинах.

Я разобрался, нужно использовать:

viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }

